# Pull to refresh in Flutter doesn't invoke onLoading function unless I switch page and come back

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, pagination

I am using a smart refresher for pagination in Flutter. It calls the below function to get data from the API on the basis of start and end date.

Whenever the smart refresher calls this function, it gives the right data the first time (with initial start and end date), but when I change the dates, it fetches new data accordingly but now when I pull it again to fetch more data, it doesn't even recognise that pull action as a valid action and nothing happens.

Unless I switch to another screen and come back, it works as expected.

If you need more info or code segments, I'll gladly provide them.

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION CALLED IN SMART REFRESHER in init() isFirst = true otherwise its false

```
Future<void> fetchAnalytics({required bool isFirst}) async {
  if (isFirst == true) {
    analyticsLoadingFirst(true);
    analyticsPage.value = 1;
    analyticsTotalPage.value = 0;
    analyticsList.clear();
  } else {
    analyticsLoading(true);
  }
  analytics.value = await RemoteServices.getStatsAnalytics(
    token: Constants.token!,
start: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'). format(analyticsStartDate.value),
end: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'). format(analytiscEndDate.value),
    page: analyticsPage.value,
  );
  if (analytics.value.data!.data!.isNotEmpty) {
    analyticsList.value = analyticsList.value + analytics.value.data!.data!;
    analyticsPage.value += 1;
    analyticsTotalPage.value = analytics.value.data!.lastPage!;
  }
  isFirst == true ? analyticsLoadingFirst(false) : analyticsLoading(false);
}
```

// THIS IS THE TAB

```
    class AnalyticsStatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const AnalyticsStatsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<AnalyticsStatsScreen> createState() => _AnalyticsStatsScreenState();
    }
    
    class _AnalyticsStatsScreenState extends State<AnalyticsStatsScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      final statsController = Get.find<StatsController>();
      late AnimationController animationController;
      late AnimationController animationController2;
      RefreshController paginateController = RefreshController();
      ScrollController? _scroll;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _scroll = ScrollController();
        animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
        animationController2 = AnimationController(vsync: this);
      }
    
      @override
      void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
        if (mounted) super.setState(fn);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        animationController.dispose();
        animationController2.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Obx(
          () => statsController.analyticsLoadingFirst.isTrue
              ? Center(
                  child: AlertWidgets.IULoading(animationController1: animationController, animationController2: animationController2),
                )
              : statsController.analytics.value.data == null
                  ? LoadingError().notFoundWidget()
                  : Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 12.h),
    
                        /// ****** Today Calendar Button ******
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Get.defaultDialog(
                              title: "Select a range",
                              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.h),
                              titleStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.sp),
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              content: SizedBox(
                                // width: 0.5.sw,
                                // height: 0.65.sw,
                                width: 0.75.sw,
                                height: 0.75.sw,
                                child: SfDateRangePicker(
                                  onSelectionChanged: _onChange,
                                  onSubmit: (value) {
                                    Get.back();
                                    statsController.analyticsPage.value = 1;
                                    statsController.analyticsTotalPage.value = 0;
                                    _scrollUp();
                                    statsController.fetchAnalytics(isFirst: true);
                                  },
                                  onCancel: () {
                                    Get.back();
                                  },
                                  headerStyle: DateRangePickerHeaderStyle(
                                    textStyle: ThemeStyles.NormalLight,
                                  ),
                                  selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
                                  maxDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  showActionButtons: true,
                                  headerHeight: 50.h,
                                  rangeTextStyle: ThemeStyles.NormalLight,
                                  selectionTextStyle: ThemeStyles.NormalLight.copyWith(color: Constants.TextWhite),
                                  initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(statsController.startDate.value, statsController.endDate.value
                                      // DateTime.now(),
                                      // DateTime.now()
                                      //     .subtract(Duration(days: 7)),
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: Get.width,
                            height: 0.06.sh,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.r),
                              border: Border.all(color: Constants.TextBlack),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                SvgPicture.asset(
                                  Constants.calender,
                                  width: 22.w,
                                  height: 22.w,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 12.w),
                                Text(
                                  'Today',
                                  style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
    
                        Expanded(
                          child: ExcludeSemantics(
                            child: Obx(
                              () => SmartRefresher(
                                // scrollController: _scroll,
                                controller: paginateController,
                                enablePullUp: true,
                                enablePullDown: false,
                                onLoading: () async {
                                  print("total page loading => ${statsController.analyticsTotalPage.value}");
                                  print("current page loading => ${statsController.analyticsPage.value}");
                                  if (statsController.analyticsTotalPage.value >= statsController.analyticsPage.value) {
                                    await statsController.fetchAnalytics(isFirst: false);
                                    if (statsController.analyticsLoading.isFalse) {
                                      paginateController.loadComplete();
                                    } else {
                                      paginateController.loadFailed();
                                    }
                                  } else {
                                    paginateController.loadNoData();
                                  }
                                },
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  controller: _scroll,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: statsController.analyticsList.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                                    // int count = index + 1;
                                    var item = statsController.analyticsList[index];
                                    return productCard(analyticsDatum: item, index: index);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 12.h),
                      ],
                    ),
        );
      }
    
      // ***** Paid Summary *****
      Widget productCard({required AnalyticsDatum analyticsDatum, int? index}) {
        // double netSales = saleDatum.amount! - (saleDatum.discount! + saleDatum.tax!) - saleDatum.refundAmount!;
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.h),
          child: Container(
            width: Get.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
              color: Constants.BackgroundSecondary,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.h, horizontal: 8.w),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: Get.width > 600 ? 10.w : 16.w,
                      height: Get.width > 600 ? 15.h : 16.h,
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        Constants.analytic,
                        // color: Colors.black,
                        // size: 30.w,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 8.w),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: Get.width * 0.55,
                            child: Text(
                              analyticsDatum.productTitle.toString(),
                              style: ThemeStyles.NormalLightW600,
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "${analyticsDatum.counts} Views",
                            style: ThemeStyles.NormalLightW600,
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void _onChange(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
        print("DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs = ${args.value.startDate}");
        if (args.value is PickerDateRange) {
          statsController.analyticsStartDate.value = args.value.startDate;
          statsController.analytiscEndDate.value = args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate;
        }
      }
    
      void _scrollUp() {
        if (_scroll!.hasClients){
          _scroll!.jumpTo(_scroll!.position.minScrollExtent);
        }
      }
    }
```

// THIS IS THE CONTROLLER BEING FOUND AT THE START OF THE TAB

```
class StatsController extends GetxController {
  var startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6)).obs;
  var endDate = DateTime.now().obs;
  var analyticsStartDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6)).obs;
  var analytiscEndDate = DateTime.now().obs;
  var analyticsLoadingFirst = false.obs;
  var analyticsLoading = false.obs;
  var analytics = AnalyticsModel().obs;
  var analyticsList = <AnalyticsDatum>[].obs;

  // ******** Analytics *******
  Future<void> fetchAnalytics({required bool isFirst}) async {
    if (isFirst == true) {
      analyticsLoadingFirst(true);
      analyticsPage.value = 1;
      analyticsTotalPage.value = 0;
      analyticsList.clear();
    } else {
      analyticsLoading(true);
    }
    analytics.value = await RemoteServices.getStatsAnalytics(
      token: Constants.token!,
      start: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(analyticsStartDate.value),
      end: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(analytiscEndDate.value),
      page: analyticsPage.value,
    );
    if (analytics.value.data!.data!.isNotEmpty) {
      analyticsList.value = analyticsList.value + analytics.value.data!.data!;
      analyticsPage.value += 1;
      analyticsTotalPage.value = analytics.value.data!.lastPage!;
    }
    isFirst == true ? analyticsLoadingFirst(false) : analyticsLoading(false);
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchAnalytics(isFirst: true);
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    startDate.value = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
    endDate.value = DateTime.now();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

I've tried to look it up in the docs of pull to refresh but found nothing

Comment: please provide your full code in order to get assistance

Comment: You can check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have loaded all the data and called the `refreshController.loadNoData()` function.

Once you call the `refreshController.loadNoData()` then `onLoading` function will not be invoked by the time you call the `refreshController.resetNoData()`.

In short, to get rid of this issue just call the `refreshController.resetNoData()` in `onRefresh` function.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I've tried this but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I figured out the reason, your answer is the right solution but slightly different. I called refreshController.resetNoData() when the date was changed (inside the onSubmit method of DateRangePicker() so the smart refresher knows the data has been updated).

Comment: @BaniAkram The actual solution may be different for each and every use case, but the you just need to take care when you are calling `refreshController.loadNoData()` then **pull to refresh** will not work by the time you again call the `refreshController.resetNoData()`.